# Does HtmlMimEmail version 2.0 provides TLS authentication option?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'd like to send email using wrapper class HtmlMimEmail version 2.0 (available from phpguru).

I'd like to know does it provides TLS authentication option as like other mail wrapper e.g. PHPMailer see below:

```
<?php
 require("class.phpmailer.php");

 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();       // set mailer to use SMTP
 $mail->Host = 'mail.xxx.com.br';  // my host here
 $mail->**SMTPSecure** = "tls";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a truly terrible way to ask a question. The package you mention (and don't even link to!) doesn't even exist any more - it's now called [rmail](http://www.rgraph.net/phpguru.html). It uses terrible packaging - PHP files are saved as `.txt`!

To answer a simple question line this, [read the code](http://www.rgraph.net/pg-downloads/rmail/Rmail%20for%20PHP/smtp.txt)!

In short, no, the rmail class does not provide TLS support.